# Save text in javascript from an other web server page

Tags: javascript, string, auto-update

I'm looking for a way to save into a string in javascript the text received from an other page in my web server.

In my project I've got a page : `http://192.168.X.Y/update` which give me one information like :`RETURN=24:6f:28:38:d1:a4:BTNLEDOFF`.

Know in my main page `http://192.168.X.Y/home` I want to use this sentence previously received to update some of my button ! I know how to update my user interface but I don't know how to have my sentence in my main page to deal with it ...

Likewise, how can I make sure that the mechanism is automatic and that the user does not need to click a button to update their interface?

Thanks for help

Hope to be understandable ...

Comment: what you're looking for is AJAX, I think, from what I understand you're trying to do

Comment: I never worked with AJAX before ! I'll try to discover what it is !

Answer (score 0):

You could add that string to localstorage and then listen for localstorage changes and update the button accordingly

`http://192.168.X.Y/update1`

```
localstorage.setItem("btn", stringtobesaved);
```

`http://192.168.X.Y/home`

```
window.addEventListener('storage', () => {
    const btnstate = localstorage.getItem("btn");
    // btnstate now equals stringtobesaved from the other file
    // Update button here.
}
```

Comment: but you need to visit page update1 before anything then...